# Solving for m in $\left ( 1+i \right )^{m}= \left ( 1-i \right )^{m}, m\in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Taking the log of both sides , I wound up with an equality that looks like this:
$$m\cdot i\left ( \ln \left ( \frac{\pi }{4} +2k\pi\right )-\ln \left ( \frac{7\pi}{4} +2k\pi\right ) \right )=0$$
which to my knowledge is satisfied only when $m=0$. However, wolfram alpha gives multiple solutions:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427edlc1a076ou

Comment: The two numbers called $k$ in your equation do not need to be equal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\left(\frac{1+i}{1-i}\right)^m=1\iff i^m=1\iff m\equiv 0\pmod{4}$$

Comment: But, what about wolfram-alpha's solution?

Comment: Suggestion: you should add the $\cdot \frac {1+i}{1+i}$ before $i^m=1$ for clarity.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD You don't need $\cdot\frac{1+i}{1+i}$ to prove $\frac{1+i}{1-i}=i$, which is equivalent to $1+i=i(1-i)$, which is true.

Comment: Wolfram-Alpha's solution doesn't suppose $m$ is an integer.

Comment: @Shemafied Try searching "[solve in integers (1+i)^m=(1-i)^m](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+in+integers+%281%2Bi%29%5Em%3D%281-i%29%5Em)".

Comment: Oh, thanks for the hint.